# Can I use less-common technical terms metaphorically?

Tags: metaphors

Can any technical term be used metaphorically? For instance, can I use the word **assimilable** which means ***capable of being absorbed and incorporated into body tissue (because it's broken down into a form that can be absorbed)*** in a sentence like "Calculus is not readily assimilable by students without appreciable Mathematics background"

I'm also wary because technical terms (*assimilable* belongs in Biology) are not always popular.

I know technical terms are already being used metaphorically. One may even use these words without realizing they've been adapted from a certain discipline for everyday use. Their derived meanings seem denotational because of its pervasive use. (I know I won't be forgiven for my lack of examples, they're not coming to mind atm. But I'm praying you get the picture.)

So my question is about the aptness of using these less common technical terms. I know I risk my audience not comprehending me when I use them, but surely there was a point in time where these very familiar (technical) expressions we use today weren't as commonplace as they are now. I hope someone understands me :-)

Comment: *Assimilate* can be used to describe the process of acquiring knowledge. Any reputable dictionary ought to tell you that.

Comment: well, I'd counter your question with another: why do you feel the need to use a metaphor when a direct approach might be easier to understand ?  Even if this is literature or fiction ...  I'd rather read "Calculus is not easily understood without a good mathematics background" than your example sentence.  Metaphors that also use jargon would most often be less clear than ordinary words. Just sayin' ...

Comment: Thanks. I guess constructing my sentences in a more asssimilable fashion is better. Hehe @HowardPautz.

Comment: @StephenAntwi "Resistance is futile, your sentences will be assimilated!" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_(Star_Trek)#Assimilation  (wow I actually managed to get a Star Trek quote in, do I get extra points ?)

Comment: Was seeking the best adjective form: assimilatable is uncommon, whereas assimilable is a biological term. But one can easily see the relation there, although it stuck out to me as if I were using it metaphorically because of my background, i think. @Robusto

Comment: My example aside, I wanted to know whether it was apt to use technical terms metaphorically. I've come across many used this way. It's simply been used so often it's become lay.

Comment: @StephenAntwi do you have another example from your field ? Such things, though perhaps not the best of English, do tend to make the language richer and interesting. It's just (obviously humorously intended) that you don't want to use a "twenty pound, momentum-carrying, steel impact device for lodging a small metallic wire" when a *hammer* suffices. (Sorry couldn't resist impacting the point of discussion. ... ok ok ... ;-P )

Comment: The answer to the question is, Yes.

Comment: It's not clear that this is a metaphor?  "assimilable" is an utterly normal adjective, look it up.  it's like saying "red" or "big".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a biologist myself but to me (and to [this dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/assimilate)) the primary meaning of *assimilate* in English is exactly the one you are looking for:

> 1. tr to learn (information, a procedure, etc) and understand it thoroughly
> 2. tr to absorb (food) and incorporate it into the body tissues

Personally, I would rephrase your example to avoid the use of *assimilable* and use *assimilated* instead:

> Calculus is not readily assimilated by students without appreciable mathematics background.

However, the basic rule is that if it is understood by your audience, then you can use it. For example, I would avoid using something like [*ubiquitylated*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ubiquitylated) to mean "marked for destruction" unless I were talking to another biologist, it depends on the specific term in question.

It also goes both ways, in biology the word *splicing* has developed a meaning that is the exact opposite of what the term means in normal English. The [dictionary definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/splice) of splicing is *to join together*:

> spliced, splic·ing, splic·es
>
> 1. a. To join (two pieces of film, for example) at the ends. b. To join (ropes, for example) by interweaving strands.
> 2. To join (pieces of wood) by overlapping and binding at the ends.
> 3. To join together or insert (segments of DNA or RNA) so as to form new genetic combinations or alter a genetic structure.
> 4. Slang To join in marriage: They went to Las Vegas to get spliced.

However, in biology we talk about introns being *spliced out* and have forgotten that the term originally referred to the joining of the exons rather than the removal of the introns.

Comment: True, it's perfectly okay to communicate with the initiated in these esoteric terms, and simpler constructions would be in order otherwise, for the sake of understanding. I could come to this conclusion myself. What I'm taking from here is that there is no hard-and-fast rule about the usage of less-common technical terms in everyday language. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenAntwi the only rule I would follow is speak in a language that your audience can get, yeah.

Comment: Sounds to me like OP is trying to hijack **assimilable** and claim it for biology. Note the reverent capital b.